# Discuss Among Yourselves

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

The answer to this riddle is a single English word.

> Within, only holes. A void all about
>   Talking back like a grave, flip the first for a shout.

Comment: Am i mistaken if i say i've seen this one before...

Comment: @ABcDexter couldn't find it on puzzlingSE...and as much as I know Hugh makes his own riddles... :)

Comment: @manshu I wasn't saying that it's a duplicate of some other from this site, but yes, a similar one is (somewhere) in the bookmarked urls.

Comment: Now you've got me wondering. I thought it was original but now that you say that... There is something familiar about it. If so, my apologies. Should make it easier to solve, right? :)

Comment: @HughMeyers is it [wordplay]

Comment: There is definitely wordplay involved.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ooh, what about...

> Moot?

Within, only holes.

> The letter O is the only letter in the middle of the word.

A void all about

> "M" and "T" spoken out loud is "empty."

Talking back like a grave,

> Reading moot backwards: toom sounds like "tomb" a grave

flip the first for a shout

> Woot!

Comment: think about how your word sounds when spoken backwards, that could give you a clue about that hint

Comment: @question_asker tomb?

Comment: @manshu shhh!!!! but yes.

Comment: @question_asker with that addition, I will accept the answer. Well done to both of you! I suppose the value of the title is debatable.

Comment: For title relevance, rot13 this badboy: `uggcf://ra.jvxgvbanel.bet/jvxv/zbbg#Abha`

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is:

> **hell**

Within, only holes. A void all about:

> hell = the abyss = void = bottomless pit / hole

Talking back like a grave, flip the first for a shout.

> I can't seem to relate it to "Talking back from a grave" but flipping the letter "h" would make the word appear like **yell** which means shout.

Comment: Notice that the letters h-e-l-l appear within the words "only holes".

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is...

> DAY

I don't have a complete explanation for all parts of the riddle, but for some...

> The title is **D**iscuss **A**mong **Y**ourselves.

Within, only holes.

> (Unsure) - possibly means the middle letter has a hole.

A void all about

> Night is either side of day.

Talking back like a grave,

> Talking back -> Backwards. 'Day' backwards is 'yad' which means 'to remember' in Hindi (Credit to manshu in comments), which is what graves are for. Also, graves are sad, which sounds like 'yad'.

flip the first for a shout.

> Flipping the first letter of 'day' gives 'bay' - a kind of shout.

Comment: 'Yad' in hindi language means 'memory' or 'to remember'...then maybe it means to remember those people who are in the grave...

Comment: Not the right answer but some of the reasoning is very much on the right track.

Comment: I think any English language puzzle which requires the solver to be fluent in Hindi (or any other language other than that in which the puzzle was given) is pretty unfair.  Unless there was some clue that indicates there was another language used.

Answer (score 2):

#### This is not the correct answer(my achievement)...confirmed by OP

I think the riddle fits for

> Trap

Within, only holes. A void all about

> Holes are used as traps for centuries.

Talking back like a grave, flip the first for a shout.

> Traps are to kill someone (sometimes). Take mouse trap for example, it flips and kills the mouse with a shriek.

Comment: There is a word that fits much better.

Comment: Also, if [your guessed word] are all about, you should probably avoid the area. "A void all about" :)

Answer (score 2):

> MOOT

Within, only holes.

> The letter O's can be considered holes

A void all about

> A moot point is often void of importance

Talking back like a grave

> A moot point is an open/unresolved question, you don't often get answers when talking to a grave

flip the first for a shout

> WOOT WOOT!

Comment: i might be suffering from Deja-vu...coz i think that i saw this kind of answer.

Comment: Yeah, it turned up while I was reading/writing...doh!